# How to share an actie sip session between activities? (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, sip

My app connects with a sip server in a couple of activities. I haven't found a way to pass a registered sip session to the next activity. This means that every time the user goes to a new activity inside the app, the app needs to "reregister" at the sip server.

Does anyone know a solution?

Kind regards,

Lucas Swartsenburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good solution would be to register the sip server in an Android service. When the app starts start the service, and when your activities start/stop on the device, bind/unbind to that service as needed. When the last activity exits, stop the service.

To make the bind/unbind easier, you could superclass your activities and make the appropriate calls in onResume() and onPause().

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Hi Jarvisteve,tnx for your answer. I'll try and post the result.